# python: creating a new column with values based on another column and then concat.?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been browsing through the form, and I don't think if this has been asked before.

I'm new to python, and I'm trying to make a script so I don't have to do manual fixes to a .csv file. I have two states where the downloaded .csv file does not give numeric values or GEOID for districts.

I want the script to identify that if the district name is Addison AND the current_chamber is 'upper', it will return ADD in the new column. This will later be concat. to give the full GEOID.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
    def uppervt_dist(state):
        df = pd.read_csv(add_data_path + r'/vt_legislators.csv'.format(state_abbreviation.lower()))
            df.insert(4, "district", date)      if state == 'VT': #should insert the column "district" in the 4th position
                if current_district = 'Addison' and current_chamber = 'upper'
                    return 'ADD'
                if current_district = 'Bennington' and current_chamber = 'upper'
                    return 'BEN'
     df.to_csv(add_data_path + r'/vt_legislators.csv'.format(state_abbreviation.lower()))
        print('Fixed VT Upper District')
```

I later want to do similar with the lower districts: if Belknap 1, return 001, if Carroll 3, return 103, etc.

My concern is that it's going to be alot of line of code to identify each district. Is there a way where I can say "for each Belknap, return 00 + the number"?

Is there an easier way to do this, or am I just over complicating matters?

Comment: Hi @marlsta, I have no so much experience using pandas but if you can provide a full python script with your current approach, and the logic you are using for assigning those codes 001 or 103 to your cities, maybe there will be more help, also a more complete specification of your CSV columns will be great

Comment: Also in python is pretty important to have the exact indentation, please verify that in the code you provide.

Comment: Hi Carpinchosaurio - they're upper and lower legislative districts, so the values are already assigned. Most of the US has numeric values, but VT seems to be the exception to the rule. - Now, for GEOID's, that's a concat of the statefp + district, so the upper legislative district of Addison, in VT would be 50ADD (50 being the statefp, ADD being the district. The lower legistlative district Belknap 1 of NH would have the GEOID of 33001. The code I want to create to fix the VT and NH issue would be added to my larger code, hence defining the action as uppervt_dist(state).

Answer (score 1):

Update: Resolved my own issue! In case anyone else has the same issue:

I made a standalone table with values associated to the district, state and chamber, along with the values I wanted to add (GEOID and corrected values that would be understood by a shapefile).

I then coded for that file to be joined to the .csv files that needed to be corrected. This was then concat. with my other files. Worked just fine!